# Importance of Hamel bases for description of additive functions

Tags: functional-equations, hamel-basis

I am unable to understand the reason and motivation of the author that why did he set
$$ f ( x ) = \sum r _ \alpha s ( h _ \alpha ) \text . $$

> The importance of Hamel bases for description of additive functions is manifested by the following
>
> **Theorem.** Let $ H $ be a Hamel basis and let $ s : H \to \mathbb R $ be an arbitrary function. Then there exists a unique additive function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $ f ( h ) = s ( h ) $ for any $ h \in H $.
>
> **Proof.** Set $ H = \{ h _ \alpha \} $. Given a function $ s : H \to \mathbb R $ we can define a function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ in the following way. Let $ x $ be an arbitrary real number. Then $ x = \sum r _ \alpha h _ \alpha $, where $ r _ \alpha \in \mathbb Q $ and only finite of the numbers $ r _ \alpha $ are nonzero. $ \require {color} \color {red} \text {Set } f ( x ) = \sum r _ \alpha s ( h _ \alpha ) \text . $ Then it is clear that $ f ( h _ \alpha ) = s ( h _ \alpha ) $ for any $ h _ \alpha \in H $ and we have to prove that $ f $ is an additive function. Let $ x = \sum r ' _ \alpha h _ \alpha $ and $ y = \sum r '' _ \alpha h _ \alpha $, where $ r ' _ \alpha , r '' _ \alpha \in \mathbb Q $. Then it follows that
> $$ \begin {align*} f ( x + y ) & = f \left( \sum ( r ' _ \alpha + r '' _ \alpha ) h _ \alpha \right) \\
> & = \sum ( r ' _ \alpha + r '' _ \alpha ) s ( h _ \alpha ) \\
> & = \sum r ' _ \alpha s ( h _ \alpha ) + \sum r '' _ \alpha s ( h _ \alpha ) \\
> & = f ( x ) + f ( y ) \end{align*} $$
> and the theorem is proved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the $r_\alpha$ in this definition depend on $x$.

The definition is such that
$$
f\left(\sum_{h_\alpha\in H} r_\alpha h_\alpha\right) = \sum_{h_\alpha\in H} r_\alpha\, s(h_\alpha)
$$
for all choices of the $r_\alpha$ (with only finitely many coefficients non-zero).

In particular, for any $h_{\alpha_0}\in H$ we can express $h_{\alpha_0}=1\cdot h_{\alpha_0}$ as such a linear combination by letting
$$
r_\alpha = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\alpha=\alpha_0$,} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}
$$
This leads to
$$
h_{\alpha_0} = \sum_{h_\alpha\in H} r_\alpha h_\alpha
$$
so that
$$
f(h_{\alpha_0}) = f\left(\sum_{h_\alpha\in H} r_\alpha h_\alpha\right) = \sum_{h_\alpha\in H} r_\alpha\, s(h_\alpha) = s(h_{\alpha_0}),
$$
which accomplishes that $f$ and $s$ agree on $H$, as desired.

Comment: Could you please tell that what is $f(h_{a_{0}}) $ ?? Also, your proof still does not actually tells that why did the author choose to set $f(x)=\sum r_{\alpha}s(h_{\alpha})$. Could you please try to be more pedantic ?

Comment: $f(h_{\alpha_0})$ is the image of $h_{\alpha_0}$, an element of $H$, under the newly defined map $f$, what is not clear about that?

Comment: could you please explain the above three questions a bit in detail....i would then understand your answer and it would be highly helpful.....please !

Comment: by $\sum r_\alpha h_\alpha$, do you mean $h_{\alpha_0}r_{\alpha_0}+h_{\alpha_1}r_{\alpha_1}+...+h_{\alpha_n}r_{\alpha_n}$ ??

Comment: Excuse me, but do you read the words between the formulas? The explanation is *there*.

Comment: yes but i am not able to understand

Comment: To express an arbitrary element of $H$, named $h_{\alpha_0}$, as a sum $\sum_{h_\alpha\in H} r_\alpha\,h_\alpha$, so we can compute $f(h_{\alpha_0})$. To do that you need to take $1$ times $h_{\alpha_0}$ itself and add $0$ times all the other elements of $H$.

Comment: We want to show that $f(h_\alpha)=s(h_\alpha)$ for all $h_\alpha\in H$. To avoid confusion ("$h_\alpha$" already appears), I used a new name and now show that $f(h_{\alpha_0})=s(h_{\alpha_0})$ for all $h_{\alpha_0}\in H$. Here "$h_{\alpha_0}$" is just a name for an arbitrary element of $H$. Since the choice is arbitrary, the result holds for *all* elements of $H$.

Comment: oh thank you very much for your help....now everything is clear to me and it was highly helpful